# In R ggplot, how do I stack two dotplots?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is,

```
$ Age        : int  20 25 30 35 40 45 50 55 60
$ Test.Positive    : int  1 0 1 1 2 2 0 1 0
$ Test.Negative : int  0 1 3 2 4 1 3 1 1
```

I am able to create individual dot plots for each as,

```
YM_R = rep(Age,YM)
df1 <- as.data.frame(YM_R) 
YP_R = rep(Age,YP)
df2 <- as.data.frame(YP_R) 

gm <- ggplot(df1) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(x=df1$YM_R, y="Y-"), color='green', fill='green', binwidth = 2)

gm <- ggplot(df2) + 
  geom_dotplot(aes(x=df2$YP_R, y="Y+"), color='red', fill='red', binwidth = 2)
```

But I don't know how to combine them. Sample of how I want is in the image attached. Any pointers appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`? BTW: since you give data already with `ggplot(df1)`, you should use `x=YM_R` instead of `x=df1$YM_R`. It doesn't seem critical now, but as you get into more `ggplot2` (and extension) features, you will not be able to use this (redundant) nomenclature.

Comment: Can you clarify what is `YM` and `YP` ?

Comment: Y is the test. YM is Test.Negative and YP is Test.Positive.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at facet_* and see if it helps me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest instead of thinking about "combining" plots, look instead to "facet" them.

Using an example from [`?geom_dotplot`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html):

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(method="histodot", binwidth=1.5)
```

[image: ggplot2, no facet]

By adding a single call to `facet_grid` (there's `facet_wrap` as well), we can break them out:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg)) +
  geom_dotplot(method="histodot", binwidth=1.5) +
  facet_grid(cyl ~ .)
```

[image: ggplot2, with facets]

Comment: Thanks r2evans. This is a great pointer. I am going to explore this and get back if I am stuck.

Comment: Realize that if you want to loosen either of the axes, you can use `facet_grid(cyl ~ ., scales = "free_x")` or `"free_y"` or more liberally `"free"`. It does change the layout a little, but depending on your needs it might give you more of what you need. (My recommendation for this plot is to *not* free up either of the x/y scales since it will introduce visual bias.)

Comment: Thanks facets + theme got what I wanted.